Navigate to specific page with back arrow button in Flutter
I have a Flutter app where I might navigate, using an external call, to a specific app page (UnlockAppsScreen). I can achieve this behaviour, but I would like to have a back arrow button in this page to navigate back to the main screen (AppScreen). To do this, I am trying to add the AppScreen to the stack before navigating to the UnlockAppsScreen.
I have this main.dart:
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await initControllers();

  // handle routing intent from foreground service
  const platform = MethodChannel("testApp/route");
  platform.setMethodCallHandler((call) async {
    if (call.method == 'navigate') {
      String route = call.arguments;
      if (route == GetRoutes.appLock) {
        Get.offNamed(GetRoutes.main);
        Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
          Get.toNamed(GetRoutes.appLock);
        });
      } else {
        Get.toNamed(route);
      }
    }
  });

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: selectedTheme,
        initialRoute: GetRoutes.splash,
        onGenerateRoute: GetRoutes.generateRoute,
      );
  }
}

class GetRoutes {
  static const String splash = "/splash";
  static const String main = "/main";
  static const String appLock = "/app_lock";

  static Route<dynamic>? generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    print(settings);
    switch (settings.name) {
      case splash:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SplashPage());
      case main:
        debugPrint("-----------------");
        debugPrint("Navigating to main");
        debugPrint("-----------------");
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AppScreen());
      case appLock:
        debugPrint("-----------------");
        debugPrint("Navigating to locked apps");
        debugPrint("-----------------");
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => UnlockAppsScreen());
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
}

The code opens the first page (from Get.offNamed(GetRoutes.main);) but never opens the second page (supposedly from Get.toNamed(GetRoutes.appLock);).
Do you have any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Use navigator.pushReplacement to go particular screen.

I understand you're facing an issue with navigation. So, currently, you've three screens (1. Splash, 2. Home, 3. App Lock).
Your initial screen is the splash screen, and after a few seconds, you want to go either to the home screen or the app lock screen (based on your method channel).
So, here I wrote a sample code for you. Initially, it'll navigate to the splash screen. After some delay, you navigate to the home screen (you can change it). And from the home screen, you can't go back to the splash screen (obviously). From the home screen, you can go to the app lock screen. Once you enter the app lock screen, you can't go back (obviously). If you pass, you can go to the home screen. If you fail, the app will close. You can't go back to the home screen from the app lock screen.
import "dart:io";

import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:get/get.dart";

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      initialRoute: "/",
      theme: ThemeData(),
      getPages: <GetPage<dynamic>>[
        GetPage<dynamic>(name: "/", page: SplashScreen.new),
        GetPage<dynamic>(name: "/mainScreen", page: MainScreen.new),
        GetPage<dynamic>(name: "/appLockScreen", page: AppLockScreen.new),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (Duration timeStamp) async {
        await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
        await Get.offAllNamed("/mainScreen");
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(child: Text("Splash Screen")),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text("Main Screen"),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async => await Get.offAllNamed("/appLockScreen"),
                child: const Text("Go to App Lock Screen"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AppLockScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppLockScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Text("App Lock Screen"),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async => await Get.offNamed("/mainScreen"),
                child: const Text("Auth Success"),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async => exit(0),
                child: const Text("Auth Failure"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


